# Handling autoconf with Android after NDK16

Tags: android-ndk, autoconf

I'm trying to update an existing configuration we have we are cross compiling for a number of targets - the question specifically here is about Android. More specifically we are building code using cmake and the hunter package manager. However we are building ICU using a link that uses autoconf/configure, called from cmake. Not sure that is specifically important except that we have less control on the use of configure than is generally the case.

OK: we have a version that builds against an old NDK but I am updating and have hit a problem identified by https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/UnifiedHeaders.md: with NDK16 and later, the value of the sysroot parameter needs to vary between compilation and linkage. As it stands the configure script tries to build a small program conftest.c - the program fails to link. Manually I can compile the code in two stages using -c and then linking the subsequent .o, but that is not what configure is trying to do.

Now the reality is that when I build this code, I don't actually need to link the code - I am generating a library which is used elsewhere. However that is not currently the way that configure sees it.

I may look to redo the configuration script to just check that the code can be compiled when cross compiling. However I am curious to know if anybody has managed to handle this sort of thing by keeping the existing config files and just changing the parameters by which the scripts are called.

Comment: Note that NDK is now preparing an [ICU wrapper](https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/548). This could make your build easier, and also reduce the deployment size significantly.

Answer (score 0):

When r19 releases to stable this problem will go away on its own (https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/780), but since that's still in beta it's not a good solution just yet.

Prior to r19 (this isn't really unique to r16+, this has always been the case and it was just asymptomatic previously), autoconf builds should be done using a [standalone toolchain](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain).

You however should *not* use a standalone toolchain for CMake, so odds are something about your configuration will need to change until r19 is released. Depending on the effort involved, it may make sense to keep to r15 until r19 is available.